# Typo3 Powermail Prefill

Tags: typo3

Im using Typo3 and got 2 Powermail Forms on a Hotel Page.

One small form on every Page where you can put the checkin and checkout date.
After this you will be redirected to the main form.

How can i prefill the daterecords from the small after the redirect in the mainform?

Both forms have the same variable names {checkin} and {checkout}

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try it..

```
 plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill {
    # Fill field with marker {current_date}
    current_date = TEXT
    current_date{
      data = date : U
      strftime = %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S
    }
    form2date = TEXT
    form2date{
      data = date : U
      strftime = %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S
    }

    seminar = CONTENT
    seminar {
      table =   tx_news_domain_model_news
      select.pidInList = 118
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.wrap = uid = |
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.insertData =1
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
            10 = TEXT
            10.dataWrap ={field:title}

      }
    }

    price = CONTENT
    price {
      table =   tx_news_domain_model_news
      select.pidInList = 118
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.wrap = uid = |
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.insertData =1
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
            10 = TEXT
            10.dataWrap ={field:price}

      }
    }

    location = CONTENT
    location {
      table =   tx_news_domain_model_news
      select.pidInList = 118
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.wrap = uid = |
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.insertData =1
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
            10 = TEXT
            10.dataWrap ={field:tx_roqnewsevent_location}
      }
    }

    event_startdate = CONTENT
    event_startdate {
      table =   tx_news_domain_model_news
      select.pidInList = 118
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.wrap = uid = |
      select.where.stdWrap.cObject.insertData =1
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
            10 = TEXT
            10.value.field = tx_roqnewsevent_startdate
            10.value.date = d-m-Y 
            #10.strftime = %d-%m-%Y 
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do i get current loggedin user usergroups with comma seperated in powermail field.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try add (width js on submit action) in form action url or redirect url width parametrs [checkin]="" and [checkout]="". Like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal powermail_form powermail_form_1" action="index.php?id=5&checkin=25.05.15&checkout=25.06.15" method="post"> 
...
```

for test try use url "yousite.com/index.php?id=5?checkin=25.05.15&checkout=25.06.15" fields in form must be fill.
Where "5" - your main form page id